# Mathematical Alphanumerical capital I symbol

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I'm looking to type this 
[image]

that I saw in a pdf document. However, when I google the mathematical alphanumerical symbols on Wikipedia, it has symbol styles for other letters, but I seems to be reserved.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use "\mathcal".

Comment: A good question (but not appropriate here) would be why these Unicode symbols are missing. ... Sometimes people say: I don't need to learn TeX, everything I need is already in Unicode.  I seems Afro found differently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\mathcal I_1` to get $\mathcal I_1$.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the omitted symbols here were thought to have already appeared earlier in Unicode.  Your Wikipedia table [says in a note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode#Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols_block)

> The reserved code points (the "holes") in the alphabetic ranges up to U+1D551 duplicate characters in the [Letterlike Symbols block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode#Letterlike_Symbols_block)

For example `U+2110` is "Script Capital I" and looks like ℐ allowing `U+1D4A4` to be ignored

while `U+210E` is "Planck Constant" and looks like ℎ allowing `U+1D455` to be ignored

Comment: +1 I was not aware you could type Unicode characters the way you did.